# How to generate path out of masked SVG path?

Tags: svg, vector-graphics, svg-path

Is there a way to generate new, stand alone path out of a path with multiple masks applied to it?

I have a `<path>` with multiple masks applied via wrapping `<g>` parents, like so:

[image]

Here is the final graphic without masks visible:

[image]

[DEMO on CodePen](http://codepen.io/sergeylukin/pen/RoaRgy)

Source code:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <mask id="primMask">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 300 0 300 300 0 300 Z
               M 100 0 A 50,50 0 0,0 100,100 A 50,50 0 0,0 100,0" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="white" />
    </mask>
    <mask id="anotherMask">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 300 0 300 300 0 300 Z
                 M 30 0 A 10,10 0 0,0 30,60 A 10,10 0 0,0 30,0" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="white" />
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <!-- These are just the circles with same paths
       as masks to help visualize the masks shape/position -->
  <g>
    <path d="M 100 0 A 50,50 0 0,0 100,100 A 50,50 0 0,0 100,0" class="maskCopy" />
    <path d="M 30 0 A 10,10 0 0,0 30,60 A 10,10 0 0,0 30,0" class="maskCopy" />
  </g>

  <!-- This is the main shape with masks -->
  <g mask="url(#primMask)">
    <g mask="url(#anotherMask)">
      <path d="M 10 10 L 90 10 70 90 10 90 Z" class="myShape" />
    </g>
  </g>

</svg>
```

Here is why I'm asking: I need to apply different styles to `myShape` on mouse hovering it's visible part only. Currently, as you can test in [DEMO](http://codepen.io/sergeylukin/pen/RoaRgy), styles are changed when mouse hovers the original path, masks are not taken into count.
Besides, I think having stand-alone path provides more flexibility in more complex requirements and also is more performant when more masks are being added.

Comment: You probably should be using clippaths rather than masks

Comment: @MichaelMullany probably, but then the question remains - how to generate new path out of masked / clipped path?